# Datasnap Server not releasing memory

Tags: delphi, datasnap

We have migrated COM/Dcom Application to Datasnap using Delphi XE2.

In COM/Dcom application memory of server gets release once user logout for application server. In case of Datasnap, memory is not getting release. If 10 user login it will consume 100 mb. Once user logout not memory is release. This 100 mb will be used for next 10 user who logsin. If more user logs in then additional memory will be utilizes. Upon logout of all user not memory is release.

onDestroyInstace in ServercontainerUnit for each module I am calling following code

```
DSDestroyInstanceEventObject.ServerClassInstance.Free;
GetInvocationMetaData.CloseSession := True;
```

Any advice or suggestion in this regard will be very helpful